# When choosing a CPU to install in a barebones laptop, what compatibility factors should one consider?

Tags: laptop, cpu

I have a sizable quantity of bare-bones HP 6570b ProBooks, and am looking at various CPU's to potentially install. The socket type is G2 and it has to be compatible with the Intel HM76 chip-set, but are there any other considerations I need to make?

Comment: How much power it takes and the amount of heat.  I find it very unlikely you will be able to replace the CPU within the laptop you have.

Comment: There is no CPU in the laptops. I am not looking to replace the CPU, I am looking to put one in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of compatible CPUs at http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-Upgrades-Replacements/probook-6570b-processor-upgrade/m-p/2392193#M16302

In short, you may want to limit yourself to
i7-3540M
i7-3520M
i5-3380M
i5-3360M
i5-3340M
i5-3320M
i5-3230M
i5-3210M
i3-3130M

You may be able to get a feel for the best speed tradeoff by getting the "Passmarks" for each CPU from http://www.cpubenchmark.net/, and then factoring in the cost of the CPU's.